# Short story from many years ago where the two main characters merge into one

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The only thing I remember is that the two main characters are lovers (perhaps one is an alien?) and they merge into one entity at the end of the tale.  "It" pours itself a cup of coffee at/near the end.  I read it in the 1960's/1970's, but it may have been written before then. Anyone know this piece?  Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very short of details. Why not have a quick read through [this checklist](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and see if you can add some more.

Comment: I remember this one. I think it might have been answered before.

Answer (score 11):

[*The Compleat Consummators*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77487) by Alan E Nourse.

It is about a dating agency who promise a perfect match.

> "One hundred per cent compatibility on all levels, or your money is
> refunded and the alliance annulled."

Something happens to the couple that are matched:

> "*Something's happening!*"
> "*Something's happening!*"
> "HELP..."
>
> There was silence then, with only the echos of a strangled scream.
>    After It had jelled for a while, It got up from the sofa and went into
> the kitchen to make a pot of coffee.